# model.fit calculates validation only once after validation_freq train epochs and then never again

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

First: I'm not able to provide any code - if that's enough reason to close this - so be it.

The codebase I was provided is confidential and I was not able to reproduce this behavior in a standalone example after multiple hours of work. It's too much custom code that I barely understand which makes isolating single parts basically impossible.

That's why I'm now trying the opposite approach: looking at the tensorflow code to find out what variable combination has to happen to cause this behaviour and then work from there.

I'm asking for advice on how to debug this issue myself / or if anyone has seen something like this:

---

**The actual Issue:**

I'm training a tensorflow model with `model.fit` and set the `validation_freq` argument to e.g. 10. The behavior I get is that validation is performed on epoch 10 and that's it. On epoch 20, 30 ... and so on no validation is performed. To summarise: for each `model.fit` call I get only one evaluation in total.
Tensorflow Version: 2.10.0

<s>I tried going directly into `site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py` to add print statements inside `model.fit` itself: [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L1203) and [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py#L2758) but I got no output so they were either not executed or print from this file doesn't reach stdout for some reason... or... I misunderstood the code flow of TensorFlow ...</s>

*I was changing `site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py` while the code was actually using `site-packages/keras/engine/training.py`*

What could cause this / how could I debug this?

Comment: So, you also expect validation score at every 10th epoch, i.e. 10, 20, 30, ...?

Comment: @Innat Yes, but I only get it once as if the code that calculates it some how burns out and does not want to run again.

Comment: If you cannot reproduce this problem in a standalone example, then the problem is probably into something you did in your codebase, which you cannot share, so we cannot really help you. Try a bit harder to reproduce this in a standalone example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly the issue if you're unable to provide examples but I would try the following.

1. make sure you are providing validation data to the `fit` method
2. Try manually setting the epochs after which to validate: `model.fit(...validation_freq=[10, 20, 30])`
3. If you're editing the source code and working out of a jupyter notebook, you probably have to restart the kernal for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will check that out and let you know what I find. This will take a few minutes / hours though (GPU is currently occupied by someone else)

Comment: You were right, the validation dataset ran out of data and the error message that should have informed me about it was suppressed by some custom logic so I didn't even consider that this could be the problem.